# Accumulative Recursion to Replace String Characters With Numbers in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, accumulator

The question is the following:

> > 1. Use accumulative recursion
> > 2. Function consumes a string and produces a new string
> > 3. Each character that appears consecutively is replaced by the letter and the number of times of its consecutive appearances
> > 4. Example: "hellooo" => "hel2o3"
> > 5. Question is University Level Based

I've tried the following:

```
(define (abbreviate str)
  (local [(define str-lst (string->list str))
          (define (count-duplicate lst char count)
            (cond
              [(empty? lst) count]
              [(equal? (first lst) char)
               (count-duplicate (rest lst)
                                (first lst)
                                (add1 count))]
              [else (count-duplicate (rest lst)
                                     (first lst)
                                     count)]))
          (define (build-string lst)
            (cond
              [(empty? lst) empty]
              [else (cons (first lst)
                          (cons (string->list (number->string 
                                         (count-duplicate (rest lst)
                                                          (first lst) 1)))
                          (build-string (rest lst))))]))]


    (build-string str-lst)))
```

But I get the result:

> (list #\h (list #\4) #\e (list #\4) #\l (list #\4) #\l (list #\3) #\o (list #\3) #\o (list #\2) #\o (list #\1))

Any help?

Comment: So I wondered, what exactly are you trying to convey when you say your question is university level (since you also annotated your last question the same way)? That it's really simple? That you're trying to cheat your assignment? Or something else? I'm really curious.

Comment: I am currently studying in a university level course. I am not looking for straight answers but help to guide me to the right path. I indicate that the question is university level because answers I get may implement concepts I have not yet learnt in class. Since I have not learnt those concepts, I am not allowed to use them in my assignments.

Comment: I see. It may be clearer to simply state that you're working on an assignment, and that the concepts you've been taught so far are: _list concepts here_. Different courses teach different concepts at different paces, so it's better to be explicit about what you're able to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, since this is a "university level" question, you're actually learning racket for a class - I assume then that you are using the Advanced Student Language Pack.

My understanding of accumulative recursion is that the program uses some type of memory. Here is a solution I worked on. It's a complete solution to the question and is completely compatible with the Advanced Student Language Pack; code's a bit clunky but you're welcome to refine it of course.

```
;; abbreviate : string -> string
;; consumes a string and produces a new string, with all occurences of
;; sequences of repeating characters reduced to 1 character and the 
;; number of times the character repeats
;; Example
;; (abbreviate "oooo) should be "o4"
;; (abbreviate "thiis iss a teesstt") should be "thi2s is2 a te2s2t2"
;; (abbreviate "magic") should be "magic"
;; Definitions:
(define (abbreviate a-string)
  (local ((define memory empty)
          (define (count-dupes b)
            (cond ((empty? b) 0)
                  ((duplicate? b) (+ 1 (count-dupes (rest b))))
                  (else 0)))
          (define (skip-dupes c n)
            (cond ((= n 0) c)
                  ((empty? c) c)
                  (else (skip-dupes (rest c) (sub1 n)))))
          (define (duplicate? a)
            (equal? (first a) (first memory)))
          (define (load lst)
            (begin (set! memory (cons (first lst) memory)) (abbreviate-x (rest lst))))
          (define (abbreviate-x lst)
            (cond ((empty? lst) lst)
                  ((empty? memory) (cons (first lst) (load lst)))
                  ((duplicate? lst) (cons (+ 1 (count-dupes lst)) 
                                          (abbreviate-x 
                                            (skip-dupes lst (count-dupes lst)))))
                  (else (cons (first lst) (load lst)))))
          (define (string-adapt d)
            (cond ((empty? d) empty)
                  ((number? (first d)) (append (string->list (number->string (first d)))
                                               (string-adapt (rest d))))
                  (else (cons (first d) (string-adapt (rest d)))))))
    (list->string (string-adapt (abbreviate-x (string->list a-string))))))
;; Test
(check-expect (abbreviate "hellooo wooorldd") "hel2o3 wo3rld2"
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

Start by unit-testing the helper procedures, some hints:

- If by *accumulative recursion* you mean *tail recursion*, then beware: `build-string` is not tail recursive, and will have to be entirely rewritten
- `count-duplicate` is not doing what you expect - it's an error to pass `(first lst)` as the second parameter in the recursive calls
- You're not counting *consecutive* characters, you're just counting the number of characters
- The output list is not being correctly constructed - why always stick a character with its frequency together? only do this if the characters are consecutively duplicated
- The expected output is a string, not a list of characters. At some point you'll have to make use of `list->string`
- Also, at some point you'll have to convert the *number* of characters found into a *character*, for example: `3` will become `#\3`. This is required for creating a string at the end

There are so many mistakes that my advice would be to start over from scratch, solving and testing the subproblems before gluing together the parts. But I'll lend you a hand with the `count-duplicate` procedure, notice that you're interested only in the number of chars that are *consecutive* for a given char, this is the correct way to do it:

```
(define (count-duplicate lst char count)
  (cond [(or (empty? lst) (not (char=? char (first lst))))
         count]
        [else
         (count-duplicate (rest lst) char (add1 count))]))
```

You'd use it like this:

```
(count-duplicate (rest '(#\h #\e #\l #\l #\o)) #\h 1)
=> 1

(count-duplicate (rest '(#\h #\h #\h #\l #\o)) #\h 1)
=> 3
```

Now you have to make sure that for each *current* character in the original string, you count how many consecutives were found in the *rest* of the list, and if the number is greater than `1`, construct the output list in the right way. Don't forget to advance the recursion `count` characters after you've found a duplicate, otherwise you'll count the same character several times! (hint: use `drop` for this).

Comment: How would I look for consecutive characters? Compare the first and the second value in the list?

Comment: That's my main issue. I can't seem to come up with a way to compare consecutive characters. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: @saurs I added some extra hints yo get you started

Comment: Thanks your tips helped me a lot! Just one issue, I am not allowed to use `drop`. Any alternative method to get the same result?

Comment: @saurs you'll have to implement by hand your own version of `drop`, there's no escape for that - necessarily, you'll have to skip over all the repeated characters when a consecutive sequence is found (think of it as a variable number of `cdr` operations for advancing the recursion)

Answer (score 1):

This works, excluding converting the final list back to a string:

```
(define (abbreviate str)
  (let scanning ((list (string->list str))
                 (last #f)
                 (numb 1)
                 (rslt '()))
    (if (null? list)
        (reverse (if (= 1 numb) rslt (cons numb rslt)))  ; after reverse, make a string
        (let ((next (car list))
              (rest (cdr list)))
          (if (equal? last next)
              (scanning rest next (+ numb 1) rslt)
              (scanning rest next 1
                        (cons next (if (= 1 numb) rslt (cons numb rslt)))))))))
```

You can see that it is fully tail recursive and that it accumulates the result as the string is traversed.

```
> (abbreviate "22")
(#\2 2)
> (abbreviate "")
()
> (abbreviate "hellllloo")
(#\h #\e #\l 5 #\o 2)
> (abbreviate "mississippi")
(#\m #\i #\s 2 #\i #\s 2 #\i #\p 2 #\i)
> (abbreviate "Noooooooooooooooooo way!")
(#\N #\o 18 #\space #\w #\a #\y #\!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take at this problem.

The first procedure called *prefix* will tell you how many consecutive identical letters you have at the beginning of a string. I'm using *string->list* to work with a list rather than with substring:

```
(define (prefix str)
  (let ((chars (string->list str)))
    (let loop ((chars chars) (c #\0) (l 0))
      (if (empty? chars)
          (values l c)
          (if (= l 0)
              (loop (cdr chars) (car chars) (add1 l))
              (if (char=? (car chars) c)
                  (loop (cdr chars) c (add1 l))
                  (values l c)))))))
```

It will return 2 values: the number of occurences, and the char in question:

```
(prefix "")
0
#\0
(prefix "x")
1
#\x
(prefix "hello")          
1
#\h
(prefix "hhhello")     
3
#\h
```

The second function *rle* will just loop over the string using the first function:

```
(define (rle str)
  (let loop ((str str) (res '()))
    (if (= (string-length str) 0)
        (string-join (reverse res) "")
        (let-values (((l c) (prefix str)))
          (loop (substring str l) 
                (cons 
                 (if (= l 1) 
                     (~a c)
                     (~a c l))
                 res))))))
```

such as

```
(rle "hellooo wooorldd")
"hel2o3 wo3rld2"
```